# get the id of one post from one page to another page in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to get the id of one object from one page to another page.

I have two pages

- index.html
- intro.html

index.html

```
 <input type="text" name="fname" value="" id="idnew">
    <a href="intro.html"><input type="button" value="Post" id="butonid"></a>

    <script>
       $("#butonid").click(function(){
               $('#idnew').val("4")
    }
    </script>
```

Now I want to send the input value of id idnew to intro.html page.

Please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269640/html-passing-value-using-query-string

Comment: use local/session storage to achieve this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331149/how-to-parse-returned-page-html-with-jquery-get

Comment: I'm confused. Can you clarify your question? It sounds like you just need to pass a variable - this is what forms are for. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Answer (score 2):

val("4") sets the value for that element, right before loading intro.html and is discarded along with your previous page.
To send that value, you could forget javascript altogether and use a form:

```
<form action="intro.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="idnew" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

then to access that value, for instance in php use $_GET['idnew']