# Several links on a web page refer to a single iframe on a separate page

Tags: html, iframe

I have several `<a>` tags on a web page that link to different Vimeo vids.  I would like to have each link when clicked load in a single iframe on separate web page.

WEBPAGE1.HTM

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126261111" target="iframe_a>EX1</a>
<a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/126263232" target="iframe_a>EX2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

WEBPAGE2.HTM

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.mycss {
cssstuff;
}
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="mycss" name="iframe_a" id="iframe_a"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This seems simple to do but I can't figure it out. Is there a way to do this only using HTML?

Comment: I would suggest you pass the video id to the target page as a querystring parameter... Then read that querystring parameter and load the video player that way.

Comment: Hi. I would love to pass a parameter to the target.  can you provide a simple example?

Comment: There are a ton of examples, here is one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269640/how-to-pass-values-from-one-html-page-to-other-using-java-script

Comment: Thanks haakon. I'll check it out.

Comment: what would be the simplest method for making this work?